# Can mock private method of supper class with jmockit

Tags: jmockit

Here is my problem: Im testing the class UnderTest, which extends SuperClass. The SuperClass has a private map ("myMap") and a private method which feels it. When Im making an instance of the UnderTest class with new() Constructor, the myMap of the super class is not initialized (in Reality this being done by the framework of the whole system, I can't do it for the cause of the test).
When running the test Im receiving NullPointerException because the map == null;
I tryed to mock the method with invoke() but I do something wrong because I still get the same exception. Where is my mistake

```
public class UnderTest extends SuperClass
{
  public void methodUnderTest()
  {....
    put(str, obj);
  ....}
}

public class SuperClass 
{
  private Map<String, Object> myMap;

  private void innerMethod (String str, Object obj)
  {....    myMap.put(str, obj);}

}
```

The class ran with jmockit

```
Class ThestSomething{

@Mocked
SuperClas superClass;

@BeforeMethod
public void setUp
{
UnderTest underTest = new UnderTest();
}


@Test
public void testThis()
{
new Expectetions {{ invoke("superClass", "innerMethod", str, obj); }};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mocking, create a properly initialized object under test:

```
public class ExampleTest {
    @Tested HashMap<String, Object> myMap;
    @Tested(fullyInitialized = true) UnderTest underTest;

    @Test
    public void example() {
        underTest.methodUnderTest();

        assertEquals(<expected value>, myMap.get("expected key"));
        // other assertions...
    }
}
```